# Filter spark DataFrame on string contains

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

I am using [Spark 1.3.0](http://spark.apache.org/releases/spark-release-1-3-0.html) and [Spark Avro 1.0.0](https://github.com/databricks/spark-avro/tree/c5612df9b1a9768689fec91655faa2a7073fd9fc#spark-sql-avro-library). 
 I am working from [the example on the repository page](https://github.com/databricks/spark-avro).  This following code works well

```
val df = sqlContext.read.avro("src/test/resources/episodes.avro")
df.filter("doctor > 5").write.avro("/tmp/output")
```

But what if I needed to see if the `doctor` string contains a substring? Since we are writing our expression inside of a string. What do I do to do a "contains"?

Answer (score 98, accepted):

You can use `contains` (this works with an arbitrary sequence):

```
df.filter($"foo".contains("bar"))
```

`like` (SQL like with SQL simple regular expression whith `_` matching an arbitrary character and `%` matching  an arbitrary sequence):

```
df.filter($"foo".like("bar"))
```

or `rlike` (like with [Java regular expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/)):

```
df.filter($"foo".rlike("bar"))
```

depending on your requirements. `LIKE` and `RLIKE` should work with SQL expressions as well.

Comment: is the above scala code? looks like scala doesn't like the $ sign. I imported `import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.lit`

Comment: Scala. To make `$` work you'll  need to `import sqlContext.implicits._`. You can replace it with `df("foo")` or `org.apache.spark.sql.functions.col("foo")` as well.

Comment: is there a similar function in pyspark?

Comment: @oluies You can use any of these ( [`like`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.Column.like), [`rlike`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.Column.rlike) directly, contains calling JVM method) on `Column` object.

Comment: @zero323 i get an error executing the code : filt_df = df.filter(\
        (col('BARCODE_ID').contains('YH','YN','YP','YT','YW','YY','3A','3G','3H')) & \
        (df.UOW_PKG_DELIV_MODE_TYPE_DESC.substr(0,17) != 'SUREPOST REDIRECT' )) --> Column not callable .. any thoughts?

Comment: @zero323 hey can I use it for multiple contains condition something like contains("bar" or "foo")?

Comment: What if I want to search a list of string (contains 10K tokens) in a single string?
Regex won't be efficient. Any other way for doing that in Spark?

Answer (score 1):

In pyspark,SparkSql syntax:

```
where column_n like 'xyz%'
```

might not work.

Use:

```
where column_n RLIKE '^xyz'
```

This works perfectly fine.