# Pyspark dataframe LIKE operator

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

What is the equivalent in Pyspark for LIKE operator?
For example I would like to do:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE column LIKE "*somestring*";
```

looking for something easy like this (but this is not working):

```
df.select('column').where(col('column').like("*s*")).show()
```

Comment: This is Scala, but pySpark will be essentially identical to this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35759099/filter-spark-dataframe-on-string-contains

Answer (score 65):

You can use `where` and `col` functions to do the same. `where` will be used for filtering of data based on a condition (here it is, if a column is like `'%string%'`). The `col('col_name')` is used to represent the condition and `like` is the operator:

```
df.where(col('col1').like("%string%")).show()
```

Comment: you can use where and col functions to do the same. where will be used for filtering of data  based on a condition (here it is, if a column is like '%s%'). The col('col_name') is used to represent the condition and like is the operator.

Answer (score 18):

Using spark 2.0.0 onwards following also works fine:

`df.select('column').where("column like '%s%'").show()`

Comment: Is there any way of including for multiple checks - I want to check for both `'%s%'` and `'%r%'`, but I only want to use `LIKE` operator like you have done.

Comment: `df.select('column').where('(col("foo").like("%s%") & (col("bar").like("%s%")')` are you looking for something like this?

Comment: Thats exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: great!! done forget to upvote :D comment and/or answer

Comment: Upvoted your answer yesterday itself and now upvoted your comment too :)

Answer (score 12):

Use the like operator.

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#module-pyspark.sql.functions

```
df.filter(df.column.like('%s%')).show()
```

Answer (score 6):

To replicate the case-insensitive `ILIKE`, you can use `lower` in conjunction with `like`.

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import lower

df.where(lower(col('col1')).like("%string%")).show()
```

Answer (score 5):

Well...there should be sql like regexp ->

```
df.select('column').where(col('column').like("%s%")).show()
```

Answer (score 5):

This worked for me:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
df.where(f.col('column').like("%x%")).show()
```

Answer (score 3):

Using [`spark 2.4`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html), to negate you can simply do:

```
df = df.filter("column not like '%bla%'")
```

Answer (score 2):

In pyspark you can always register the dataframe as table and query it.

```
df.registerTempTable('my_table')
query = """SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE column LIKE '*somestring*'"""
sqlContext.sql(query).show()
```

Comment: In Spark 2.0 and newer use `createOrReplaceTempView` instead, registerTempTable is deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

Also `CONTAINS` can be used:

`df = df.where(col("columnname").contains("somestring"))`

Answer (score -3):

I always use a UDF to implement such functionality:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F 
like_f = F.udf(lambda col: True if 's' in col else False, BooleanType())
df.filter(like_f('column')).select('column')
```

Comment: While functional, using a python UDF will be slower than using the column function `like(...)`. The reason for this is using a pyspark UDF requires that the data get converted between the JVM and Python. Furthermore, the dataframe engine can't optimize a plan with a pyspark UDF as well as it can with its built in functions.