# How to write "like '%ABC%' " in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

How can I write the following filter in Spark `TYPE_FIELD like '%ABC%'`.

Is it the same as `df.filter($"TYPE_FIELD"==="ABC")` ?

Comment: @ErnestKiwele: I don't want to use `HiveContext`

Comment: Seen answers on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40220943/pyspark-dataframe-like-operator? First answer seems to use a data frame

Comment: @ErnestKiwele: Cool, thanks.