# How to add switch case for like operator in scala?

Tags: regex, scala, apache-spark, switch-statement, case

I have a data frame with column (A, B) where column B is free test which I am converting to type (NOT_FOUND, TOO_LOW_PURCHASE_COUNT and etc) to aggregate better. I created a switch case of all possible patter and their respective type but it is not working.

```
def getType(x: String): String = x match {
    case "Item % not found %" =>"NOT_FOUND"
    case "%purchase count % is too low %" =>"TOO_LOW_PURCHASE_COUNT"
    case _ => "Unknown"
}

getType("Item 75gb not found") 

val newdf = df.withColumn("updatedType",getType(col("raw_type")))
```

This gives me "Unknown". Can some one tell me how to do switch case for like operator ?

Comment: there is no "like operator" in scala. Sounds like you need to read up on [regular expressions](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.3/scala/util/matching/Regex.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL symbol "%" in regexp world can be replaced with ".*". UDF can be created for match value to patterns:

```
val originalSqlLikePatternMap = Map("Item % not found%" -> "NOT_FOUND",
  // 20 other patterns here
  "%purchase count % is too low %" -> "TOO_LOW_PURCHASE_COUNT")
val javaPatternMap = originalSqlLikePatternMap.map(v => v._1.replaceAll("%", ".*") -> v._2)

val df = Seq(
  "Item foo not found ", "Foo purchase count 1 is too low ", "#!@"
).toDF("raw_type")

val converter = (value: String) => javaPatternMap.find(v => value.matches(v._1)).map(_._2).getOrElse("Unknown")
val converterUDF = udf(converter)

val result = df.withColumn("updatedType", converterUDF($"raw_type"))
result.show(false)
```

Output:

```
+--------------------------------+----------------------+
|raw_type                        |updatedType           |
+--------------------------------+----------------------+
|Item foo not found              |NOT_FOUND             |
|Foo purchase count 1 is too low |TOO_LOW_PURCHASE_COUNT|
|#!@                             |Unknown               |
+--------------------------------+----------------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `when` and `like`

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.when

val df = Seq(
  "Item foo not found",  "Foo purchase count 1 is too low ", "#!@"
).toDF("raw_type")

val newdf = df.withColumn(
  "updatedType",
  when($"raw_type" like "Item % not found%", "NOT_FOUND")
    .when($"raw_type" like "%purchase count % is too low%", "TOO_LOW_PURCHASE_COUNT")
    .otherwise("Unknown")
)
```

Result:

```
newdf.show
// +--------------------+--------------------+
// |            raw_type|         updatedType|
// +--------------------+--------------------+
// |  Item foo not found|           NOT_FOUND|
// |Foo purchase coun...|TOO_LOW_PURCHASE_...|
// |                 #!@|             Unknown|
// +--------------------+--------------------+
```

Reference:

- [Spark Equivalent of IF Then ELSE](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39048229/10458963)
- [Filter spark DataFrame on string contains](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35759099/10458963)

Comment: The issue is I have around 20 patterns and creating a When is little bigger for 20 cases.