# Drop any row with NULL

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a small problem. I would like to delete any row that contains 'NULL'.

**This is my input file:**

```
matricule,dateins,cycle,specialite,bourse,sport
0000000001,1999-11-22,Master,IC,Non,Non
0000000002,2014-02-01,Null,IC,Null,Oui
0000000003,2006-09-07,Null,Null,Oui,Oui
0000000004,2008-12-11,Master,IC,Oui,Oui
0000000005,2006-06-07,Master,SI,Non,Oui
```

I did a lot of research and found a function called drop(any). Which basically drops any rows that contains NULL value. I tried using it in the code below but it wont work

```
val x = sc.textFile("/home/amel/one")

val re = x.map(row => {
  val cols = row.split(",")
  val cycle = cols(2)
  val years = cycle match {
    case "License" => "3 years"
    case "Master" => "3 years"
    case "Ingeniorat" => "5 years"
    case "Doctorate" => "3 years"
    case _ => "other"
  }
  (cols(1).split("-")(0) + "," + years + "," + cycle + "," + cols(3), 1)
}).reduceByKey(_ + _)
re.collect.foreach(println)
```

**This is the current result of my code:**

```
(1999,3 years,Master,IC,57)
(2013,NULL,Doctorat,SI,44)
(2013,NULL,Licence,IC,73)
(2009,5 years,Ingeniorat,Null,58)
(2011,3 years,Master,Null,61)
(2003,5 years,Ingeniorat,Null,65)
(2019,NULL,Doctorat,SI,80)
```

**However, I want the result to be like this:**

```
(1999, 3 years, Master, IC)
```

I.e., any row that contains 'NULL' should be removed.

Comment: Once again, not mapreduce. I have removed the mapreduce tag from your post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Similar but not duplicate question as the following question on SO: [Filter spark DataFrame on string contains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35759099/filter-spark-dataframe-on-string-contains/35759345)

You can filter this RDD when you read it in.

```scala
val x = sc.textFile("/home/amel/one").filter(!_.toLowerCase.contains("null"))
```

Comment: Hi again. You have "Null" listed in the data. But you have "NULL" listed as the requirement. I have changed the code so that it is case-insensitive.

Comment: Hey! Yes I have deleted my comment after the small mistake I made. Thank you